# Invalid identifier on hibernate @Column different property name throws an error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Environment:

- Java 11
- Jboss 7.2
- Hibernate 5.3.7

I have mapped a database field (USUARIMOD) with a different name property in java class (usuariupd) but when I try to query the table I get this **error**:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "OFERTAINSC0_"."USUARIUPD": identificador no válido
...
```

Any idea?

**OfertaInscripcio**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AF_OFE_OFERTA_INSCRIPCIO")
public class OfertaInscripcio
  ...
  @Column(name = "USUARIMOD")
  private String usuariUpd;
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

you can change the column value to lowercase.

example:
Instead of using **@Column(name = "USUARIMOD")** you can use this
**@Column(name = "usuarumod")**

Comment: Sorry, wrong question, it is something else, can you delete your answer to delete the question?